# Some tailwindcss' default colors are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Some tailwindcss' default colors aren't working when I use text-color-XXX , the text is just black. It is only working for 5 combinations, listed below.

Surprisingly, in VSCode, [I can see the palette of colors appearing when I write for example text-slate-400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AafgQ.png) , or any other combination, but it will appear black on my web document anyway, except for the 5 below.

Same goes for bg-... , a very few are working.

I noticed that the colors that work are written in the css file which is linked with my .html doc.

```css
.text-gray-700 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(55 65 81 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.text-red-500 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(239 68 68 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.text-white {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.text-blue-500 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(59 130 246 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.text-red-700 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(185 28 28 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

So I don't understand why the colors I write in my .html file with tailwind are not writing the colors in the css file anymore.

And if I add a color manually in my .css file, it is working in my final document, but I'd like not to write every tailwind's default color manually.

Here is my tailwind.config.js .

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./public/html/*.html"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Tailwind parses your files where you add classes and generates css classes only from the classes that are used. Are you running the build script?

Comment: What do you mean by build script please ? I'm not running anything particular, just saving my .html and it actualizes my web doc.

Comment: Check the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: So I have to run this build script everytime I launch VSCode and I want to use tailwindcss ?

Comment: Run it with the --watch parameter (as in the docs) while you are developing, and it will run automatically each time you save a file.